# Is there a way to add to the balance on a GAE-app?

Tags: google-app-engine, billing

My problem is that i keep getting small incremental withdraws on my creditcard, which is fine - but since i run a company i need to book all those micropayments. Which ends up to be hours of work (finding, printing, put in my cover etc) each month.

I'd rather just add $100 or so to the balance and deal with just the one charge.

This seems like a "must have"-feature, especially since the terminology "balance" is used on the "Billing history"-page. But i cannot seem to find where to add money.

Is it possible?

Comment: We are getting weekly withdrawals. How often do you get them?

Comment: It's weekly for me as well, but i run five different apps. So it sums up to 20 micropayments (rarely over $2 each) per month.